# npm dependency shared by different packages gets installed twice

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm using two packages that have the same dependency: `"aws-sdk": "^2.22.0"`.

When I run `npm install`, both packages install the same package in their own `node_modules` subdirectories, like this:

```
my_project
    node_modules
        package_1
            node_modules
                aws_sdk
                    ...
        package_2
            node_modules
                aws_sdk
                    ...
        aws_sdk
        ...
```

You'll notice that my base project also uses aws-sdk so it gets installed a third time.

My project alone weights under 100kb, but the aws-sdk package weights ~ 17MB, bringing the total size to ~ 50MB, which is ridiculous.

I tried `npm dedupe` and the `flatten-packages` package, it makes no difference.

What can I do to make npm install it only once?

I'm using Windows 10, node 7.4.0 and npm 4.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to be done about this...this is how `node.js` module dependency was designed.

Each module is installed along with it's dependencies. This way, if you decide to use a different version of `aws_sdk`, your modules will still work because they're packaged with their corresponding version of their `aws_sdk`.

This is different than`Ruby on Rails` for example, where a single version of a package (gem) can be used across the application.

`npm` might do some optimizations on it's own, but it's better just to leave it do its job.

You can read more [here](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/).